# Django - 'JobProficienciesFormFormSet' object is not callable

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am having an issue when trying to `edit` a form in a template with a regular `form` and a `formset`, I receive this error when I try to save the update rows. The page populates correctly. I'm not sure what the primary error is of this.

The traceback in `python` is stating:

```
'JobProficienciesFormFormSet' object is not callable
At line 100:  form = proficiencies_formset(request.POST)
```

Here is my code:

***views.py***

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def edit(request, jobid):

    # Get the job so we can edit. Also, for checking if the company logged in is valid
    job = Jobs.objects.get(id=jobid)

    # Permission check
    if job.user_id == request.user.id:

        # Get associated Job Proficiencies IDs attached to a Job
        profid = JobProficiencies_Proficiencies.objects.filter(job_id=jobid).select_related('job_proficiencies_id')
        # Get the Proficiency values attached to the job
        qset = JobProficiencies.objects.filter(id__in=profid).select_related('job_proficiency', 'proficiency_required', 'comfort_level')

        job_proficiencies = modelformset_factory(JobProficiencies, max_num=10, extra=0)
        proficiencies_formset = job_proficiencies(queryset=qset)

        args = {}
        args.update(csrf(request))
        args = {
            'id': jobid,
            'job': JobForm(instance=job),
            'job_proficiencies_formset': proficiencies_formset,
        }

        if request.method == 'POST':
            job = JobForm(request.POST, instance=job)
            form = proficiencies_formset(request.POST)

            if job.is_valid() and proficiencies_formset.is_valid():

                m_tags = job.cleaned_data['m_tags']
                _job = job.save(commit=False)
                _job.id = jobid
                _job.dateUpdated = datetime.now()
                _job.save()

                # Save proficiencies
                for f in form:
                    job_proficiency = f.save(commit=False)
                    job_proficiency.save()
                    JobProficiencies_Proficiencies.objects.update(job_id=_job.id, job_proficiencies_id=job_proficiency.id)

                # Without this next line the tags won't be saved.
                for m_tag in m_tags:
                    job.tags.add(m_tag)

                messages.success(request, "Job Edited!")
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/job/all/')

            else:
                messages.error(request, "There are form errors!")
                return render_to_response('job/edit.html/', args, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

        return render_to_response('job/edit.html', args, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    HttpResponseRedirect('job/all/')
```

***forms.py***

```
class JobForm(forms.ModelForm):

    m_tags = TagField()
    class Meta:
        model = Jobs
        fields = ('title', 'about', 'wage', 'gitHubLink')

    def save(self, commit=True):
        job = super(JobForm, self).save(commit=False)
        job.title = self.cleaned_data['title']
        job.about = self.cleaned_data['about']
        job.wage = self.cleaned_data['wage']
        job.gitHubLink = self.cleaned_data['gitHubLink']
        job.dateUpdated = datetime.now()
        job.status = 'JO'

        if commit:
            job.save()
        return job


class JobProficienciesForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = JobProficiencies
        fields = ('job_proficiency', 'proficiency_required', 'comfort_level')

    def save(self, commit=True):
        jobproficiency = super(JobProficienciesForm, self).save(commit=False)
        jobproficiency.job_proficiency = self.cleaned_data['job_proficiency']
        jobproficiency.proficiency_required = self.cleaned_data['proficiency_required']
        jobproficiency.comfort_level = self.cleaned_data['comfort_level']

        if commit:
            jobproficiency.save()
        return jobproficiency
```

Again, the template populates correctly. The error is on saving the edit. That's where I am stuck. Any assistance is much appreciated. Thank you!

***EDIT*** Here is how I'm displaying the formset in the template:

```
                {{ job_proficiencies_formset.management_form }}
                {% for p in job_proficiencies_formset %}
                    {{ p.id }}
                    <div class="row item">
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            {{ p.job_proficiency|add_class:"form-control" }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            {{ p.comfort_level|add_class:"form-control" }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            {{ p.proficiency_required|add_class:"form-control" }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                            <p><a id="delete-row" class="delete-row" href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-2x"></i></a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At that point in the code, `proficiencies_formset` is a formset object, not a class.

```
        proficiencies_formset = job_proficiencies(queryset=qset)
...
        form = proficiencies_formset(request.POST)
```

I think what you mean there is:

```
        proficiencies_formset = job_proficiencies(request.POST)
```

And then later:

```
            # Save proficiencies
            for f in proficiencies_formset:
```

This kind of thing is one reason I like to maintain the convention of using capital letters to begin class names, even when the class is constructed by a factory.

Comment: Hello Peter! Thank you very much, that removed the error and I see your point. My naming conventions are kind of all over the place as I learn Django. :) I plan to go back and refactor the names.

Comment: When making the changes you stated, that works. However, now I am getting the error:

MultiValueDictKeyError at line 96:
if job.is_valid() and proficiencies_formset.is_valid(): 

I'm quite new to formsets so I assume this has to do with that?

Comment: How are you rendering the form in the template? I don't think I've ever run into that particular error, but formsets have some special rendering requirements - that's one place to check. Also, I'm seeing some references to special requirements for subclassed models - is `JobProficiencies` a subclass of a non-abstract class?

Comment: Apologies for the naming conventions. `JobProficiencies` is a `model` to store Proficiencies related to a job. 

Here is how I'm rendering the form in the template. Doing some looking around, it seems that if I pass the `p.id` with the form, it should remove the `MultiValueDictKeyError` as that is not being set when the form is saved and goes to be validated.

Comment: Peter, check out my edit on the initial question for how I'm displaying the formset in the template. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ah, yeah, if you're rendering the formset fields yourself you have to make sure the ID field is included. I don't recall what widget gets used by default - there are ways to force it to use a hidden input so it doesn't throw off your HTML, if it doesn't already. BTW - are you aware that your formset isn't using your custom defined `JobProficienciesForm` form class? Also, your custom `save` on both model forms are doing some redundant work - the standard `save` sets values based on `cleaned_data` already, so your `JobForm` save can be simplified and `JobProficienciesForm` doesn't need one.